# Could not open input "video=Webcam C170". (Has setFormat() been called?)

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I am trying to run code, but this error shows up. I am using Netbeans on windows, jdk-9, javacv 1.3.2, opencv 3.1.0-1.2. What could be the solution to this?

**Part from the main code:**

```
public void start() {       
    frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video=Webcam C170");
    frameGrabber.setFormat("dshow");
    frameGrabber.setImageWidth(1280);
    frameGrabber.setImageHeight(720);

    logger.debug("Starting frame grabber");
    try {
        frameGrabber.start();  //line 72
        logger.debug("Started frame grabber with image width-height : {}-{}", frameGrabber.getImageWidth(), frameGrabber.getImageHeight());
    } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error when initializing the frame grabber", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start the FrameGrabber", e);
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        window.setVisible(true);
    });

    process();

    logger.debug("Stopped frame grabbing.");
}
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: avformat_open_input() error -5: Could not open input "video=Webcam C170". (Has setFormat() been called?)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:535)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:465)
    at org.imesha.examples.javacv.JavaCVExample.start(JavaCVExample.java:72)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass filename as constructor parameter, but with extension? Based on source file the FFmpegFrameGrabber has 3 constructors and one of option is to pass a String called filename, which mostly means a file name + its extension like "yourfile.mpeg"

Comment: Hi! How exactly should I do that? I am fairly new to all of this, could you show me an example how to do it or add it to provided code? Thanks!

Comment: Try to create a File file = new File(pathToYourFile), then pass a file to FFmpegFrameGrabber. Check if your path to file is correct by invocation of file.exists().